# Deleting cache from Netbeans 8.2 not helping in adding external .jar library

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, compiler-errors, libraries

I'm trying to add external library (.jar) by Tools->Libraries etc. but I still receive errors. I even tried deleting chache folder of NetBeans - with no result. What else can I do? It's rather strange I cannot add this external library....

My code for adding this driver:

```
 public Connection getConnection() {
    try {  
        //step1 load the driver class  
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

        //step2 create  the connection object  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.login, this.password);  

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } 
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return connection;
}
```

The errors I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mycompany.myproject.ConnectionToOracle.getConnection(ConnectionToOracle.java:47)
    at org.apache.jsp.mainPage_jsp._jspService(mainPage_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Do you have the Oracle jdbc driver installed?

Comment: How should I do this?

Comment: Good question. That is what is missing. Check the documentation or ask the author.

Comment: Any advise how should I do this?

Comment: youre not using maven or gradle, it's just netbeans project, right?

Comment: I'm using maven

Comment: if you're using maven you should add your depenendecies in maven configuratin XML file

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how should it look like?

Comment: if you're getting SQLException and not ClassNotFoundException any more you have the dependency it's just not loaded?

Comment: Ok, I've done it. Great idea of adding dependency to maven - add it as answer and I'll  mark it as best ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Oracle SQL driver *.jar to your project configuration, as described on https://www.developer.com/java/data/creating-a-jdbc-application-in-netbeans-a-step-by-step-guide.html

In case of a Maven or Gradle project, you need to add the driver dependency to the pom.xml / build.gradle file as written on https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html

Comment: To be honest I've done it and still have the problem :-( What do you suggest to do?

Comment: I receive this error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found forjdbc:oracle:thin:@ ...

Comment: I finally managed to do this - I was missing dependency in pom.xml file. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You might want to use this opportunity to improve your understanding of how Maven works.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone could struggle with this like me...

Just remember to add dependency to your pom.xml file (**it is not mentioned in answers to other questions on StackOverflow**):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>{your numer of ojdbc6 version}</version>
    </dependency>
```